# Calculate overlap durations for time overlaps in MySQL

Tags: mysql

i have a database table containing events:

```
CREATE TABLE events
(event VARCHAR(32)
,down_time TIMESTAMP
,up_time TIMESTAMP
,id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY
,INDEX(event(16))
);

INSERT INTO events(event, down_time, up_time) VALUES
('e1', '2015-01-01 00:00:03', '2015-01-01 00:00:08'),
('e2', '2015-01-01 00:00:05', '2015-01-01 00:00:06'),
('e3', '2015-01-01 00:00:02', '2015-01-01 00:00:09'),
('e4', '2015-01-01 00:00:01', '2015-01-01 00:00:04'),
('e5', '2015-01-01 00:00:07', '2015-01-01 00:00:10');

select * from events;
| event | down_time           | up_time             | id |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| e1    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |  1 |
| e2    | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 |  2 |
| e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  3 |
| e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 |  4 |
| e5    | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:10 |  5 |
```

I find event overlaps using the following query (query1):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM events a 
  JOIN events b 
    ON a.down_time <= b.up_time 
   AND a.up_time >= b.down_time 
 WHERE a.id < b.id 
   AND a.event != b.event 
   AND a.event regexp 'e[1-5]' 
   AND b.event regexp 'e[1-5]';
```

which produces the following event overlaps (results1):

```
| event | down_time           | up_time             | id | event | down_time           | up_time             | id |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+
| e1    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |  1 | e2    | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 |  2 |
| e1    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |  1 | e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  3 |
| e1    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |  1 | e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 |  4 |
| e1    | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 |  1 | e5    | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:10 |  5 |
| e2    | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 |  2 | e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  3 |
| e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  3 | e4    | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 |  4 |
| e3    | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 |  3 | e5    | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:10 |  5 |
+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+-------+---------------------+---------------------+----+
```

I want to show overlap durations for each row in event overlaps (results1) and currently use the following conditional tests within PHP:

```
    if (a.down_time <= b.down_time && b.up_time <= a.up_time)
    {
    overlap_duration = b.up_time-b.down_time;
    }
    else if (a.down_time >= b.down_time && a.up_time <= b.up_time)
    {
    overlap_duration = a.up_time-a.down_time;
    }
    else if (a.down_time <= b.down_time)
    {
    overlap_duration = a.up_time-b.down_time;
    }
    else if (a.down_time >= b.down_time)
    {
    overlap_duration = b.up_time-a.down_time;
    }
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
|   |   |----------e1-------|   |   |
|   |   |   |   | e2|   |   |   |   | a.down_time <= b.down_time && b.up_time <= a.up_time
|   |------------e3-------------|   | a.down_time >= b.down_time && a.up_time <= b.up_time
|----e4-----|   |   |   |   |   |   | a.down_time >= b.down_time
|   |   |   |   |   |   |-----e5----| a.down_time <= b.down_time
```

and then produce the following output (results2):

```
|  event    | down_time            | up_time              | duration    |
|  e1       | 2015-01-01 00:00:03    2015-01-01 00:00:08    00:00:00:05 |
|  e2       | 2015-01-01 00:00:05    2015-01-01 00:00:06    00:00:00:01 |
|  Overlap1 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05    2015-01-01 00:00:06    00:00:00:01 |
|           |                                                           |
|  e1       | 2015-01-01 00:00:03    2015-01-01 00:00:08    00:00:00:05 |
|  e3       | 2015-01-01 00:00:02    2015-01-01 00:00:09    00:00:00:07 |
|  Overlap2 | 2015-01-01 00:00:03    2015-01-01 00:00:08    00:00:00:05 |
|           |                                                           |
|  e1       | 2015-01-01 00:00:03    2015-01-01 00:00:08    00:00:00:05 |
|  e4       | 2015-01-01 00:00:01    2015-01-01 00:00:04    00:00:00:03 |
|  Overlap3 | 2015-01-01 00:00:03    2015-01-01 00:00:04    00:00:00:01 |
|           |                                                           |
|  e1       | 2015-01-01 00:00:03    2015-01-01 00:00:08    00:00:00:05 |
|  e5       | 2015-01-01 00:00:07    2015-01-01 00:00:10    00:00:00:03 |
|  Overlap4 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07    2015-01-01 00:00:08    00:00:00:01 |
|           |                                                           |
|  e2       | 2015-01-01 00:00:05    2015-01-01 00:00:06    00:00:00:01 |
|  e3       | 2015-01-01 00:00:02    2015-01-01 00:00:09    00:00:00:07 |
|  Overlap5 | 2015-01-01 00:00:05    2015-01-01 00:00:06    00:00:00:01 |
|           |                                                           |
|  e3       | 2015-01-01 00:00:02    2015-01-01 00:00:09    00:00:00:07 |
|  e4       | 2015-01-01 00:00:01    2015-01-01 00:00:04    00:00:00:03 |
|  Overlap6 | 2015-01-01 00:00:02    2015-01-01 00:00:04    00:00:00:02 |
|           |                                                           |
|  e3       | 2015-01-01 00:00:02    2015-01-01 00:00:09    00:00:00:07 |
|  e5       | 2015-01-01 00:00:07    2015-01-01 00:00:10    00:00:00:03 |
|  Overlap7 | 2015-01-01 00:00:07    2015-01-01 00:00:09    00:00:00:02 |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I suspect it may be better to calculate overlap durations within MySQL by processing results1 to produce results2
but not sure how best to proceed .. if at all? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as expected

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*,
    (least(a.up_time, b.up_time) - greatest(a.down_time, b.down_time)) as overlap_seconds
  FROM events a 
  JOIN events b 
    ON a.down_time <= b.up_time 
   AND a.up_time >= b.down_time 
 WHERE a.id < b.id 
   AND a.event != b.event
   AND a.event regexp 'e[1-5]' 
   AND b.event regexp 'e[1-5]'
GROUP BY a.id, b.id;
```

to get the overlap, all you need to do is compare the "smallest" up_time with the "biggest" down_time for each row ...

Comment: many thanks Basile thats perfect!. 

I would also like to identify if all events overlap at any one time. 
So in the above dataset e1, e2,and e3 all overlap here:               Overlap |overlap_down_time     | overlap_up_time      | overlap_duration
2.1       |2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01

whereas e1,e2,e3 and e4 do not all overlap together. I had thought about checking for overlaps on the returned overlaps but not sure if that would work?

Comment: no worries, do you have your answer with Bernd Buffen's reply ?

Comment: no ..not to my additional requirement of identifying all overlaps that intersect in time ..any ideas appreciated !

Comment: @user2149346, not sure to understand your request here ... but since your original question has been answered, I'd suggest you open a new post with your additional request (note : don't forget to up-vote ;))

Answer (score 1):

With this sample you get 1 row for each block of your output.

```
SELECT
  e1.event AS event1_name,
  e1.down_time AS event1_down_time,
  e1.up_time AS event1_up_time,
  TIMEDIFF(e1.up_time, e1.down_time) AS event1_duration,

  e2.event AS event2_name,
  e2.down_time AS event2_down_time,
  e2.up_time AS event2_up_time,
  TIMEDIFF(e2.up_time, e2.down_time) AS event1_duration,

  GREATEST(e1.down_time,e2.down_time) AS overlap_down_time, 
  LEAST(e1.up_time,e2.up_time) AS overlap_up_time,
  TIMEDIFF( LEAST(e1.up_time,e2.up_time),
  GREATEST(e1.down_time,e2.down_time) ) AS overlap_duration

 FROM events e1

INNER JOIN events e2 ON e1.id < e2.id
WHERE
 ( e2.down_time <= e1.up_time ) 
AND
 ( e2.up_time >= e1.down_time );
```

Output:

```
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| event1_name | event1_down_time    | event1_up_time      | event1_duration | event2_name | event2_down_time    | event2_up_time      | event1_duration | overlap_down_time   | overlap_up_time     | overlap_duration |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
| e1          | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 | 00:00:05        | e2          | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01        | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01         |
| e1          | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 | 00:00:05        | e3          | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 | 00:00:07        | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 | 00:00:05         |
| e1          | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 | 00:00:05        | e4          | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 00:00:03        | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 00:00:01         |
| e1          | 2015-01-01 00:00:03 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 | 00:00:05        | e5          | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:10 | 00:00:03        | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:08 | 00:00:01         |
| e2          | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01        | e3          | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 | 00:00:07        | 2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01         |
| e3          | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 | 00:00:07        | e4          | 2015-01-01 00:00:01 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 00:00:03        | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:04 | 00:00:02         |
| e3          | 2015-01-01 00:00:02 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 | 00:00:07        | e5          | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:10 | 00:00:03        | 2015-01-01 00:00:07 | 2015-01-01 00:00:09 | 00:00:02         |
+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: hi Bernd Buffen ..I would also like to identify if all events overlap at any one time. 
So in the above dataset e1, e2,and e3 all overlap here: 
Overlap |overlap_down_time   | overlap_up_time     | overlap_duration 
2.1     |2015-01-01 00:00:05 | 2015-01-01 00:00:06 | 00:00:01 
whereas e1,e2,e3 and e4 do not all overlap together. 
I had thought about checking for overlaps on the returned overlaps 
but not sure if that would be implemented?